# Циклический сдвиг массива в Python: Неправильный формат вывода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброго времени суток, решаю задачу на [сайте](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=1190&chapterid=1586#1)

---

Напишите эффективную программу, которая будет циклически сдвигать заданный массив на k элементов вправо. Дополнительные массивы и рекурсию не использовать.

Входные данные
На вход программе сначала подаются значения n100 — количество элементов в массиве и k100. В следующей строке входных данных расположены сами элементы массива — целые числа, по модулю не превосходящие 30 000.

---

```
n, m = input().split()
n = int(n)
k = int(m)
array = input().split()
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = int(array[i])
array = array[-k:] + array[:-k]

print(array)
```

Пишут: Неправильный формат вывода.
В чем мой косяк?

Comment: Описание желаемого формата вывода следует прямо в вопросе приводить. Также следует показать что ваш код сейчас выводит (буквальный пример прямо в вопросе).

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде ошибки

```
n, m = input().split()
```

Нет инициализации переменной `m`

```
n = int(n)
k = int(m)
```

Нельзя преобразовать массив в тип `int`

> Дополнительные массивы и рекурсию не использовать.

Вы используете массив `array`

Comment: Если ввод содержит пробел, то split() больше одного значения возвращает (попробуйте пару чисел ввести). То есть `m` также значение имеет либо исключение выбрасывается. И соответсвенно `n` не "массив" строк, а просто одна из двух строк.